# Faulty input through command line arguments

Tags: java

There will be multiple integers in the input. You have to write a computer program to read each integer and print Even if the integer is divisible by 2, else print Odd.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count, i = 1;
        String string;
        count = args.length;
        System.out.println();
        while (i < count) {
            string = args[i];
            i = i + 1;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Even");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Odd");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The next line is going but after giving even no. it show odd and giving odd is show even.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't test whether your *counter variable* `i` is odd or even but rather the thing in `args[i]`.  Also note that the idiomatic way to iterate over an array is `for (String arg : args) { ... }`.  For one, your mistake cannot happen if you are using this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class Main {
public static void main(String arg[]){

    int i;
    i=Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);              //taking command line input from user and converting string to integer.
    if(i%2==0)
        {
         System.out.println("No. is even");
    }
    else
        {
         System.out.println("No. is odd");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It also needs a loop.